# What are The Valid & Readable approaches to Commenting in PHP5?

Tags: php, coding-style, comments

In the past 2 months that I have been learning PHP, I have identified more than two styles people use to comment code! I haven't seen much consistency... which I think usually means *artists at work*. So I wondered: what are the valid ways to comment which are still readable/practical? Seeing all the valid possibilities in 1 place side by side will provide the overview that I am looking for to improve commenting

```
/*
|  This is what I now use (5chars/3lines) I name it star*wars
\*
```

Comment: Got an editor that highlights you comments?

Comment: @Colonel yessir: *DreamWeaver* & *Notepad2 Bookmark Edition* do color em. However the Amount & Style of writing comments makes them to me readable, or not. I guesse a good lazy commenter who first thinks about short essential comment is more difficult than meets the eye. I sometimes cannot even decode my own comments. Is this normal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting the Manual on Comments:

> PHP supports 'C', 'C++' and Unix shell-style (Perl style) comments. For example:

```
<?php
    echo 'This is a test'; // This is a one-line c++ style comment
    /* This is a multi line comment
       yet another line of comment */
    echo 'This is yet another test';
    echo 'One Final Test'; # This is a one-line shell-style comment
?>
```

In general, you will want to [avoid using comments in your sourcecode](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/comments). To quote Martin Fowler:

> When you feel the need to write a comment, first try to refactor the code so that any comment becomes superfluous.

which means something like

```
// check if date is in Summer period
if ($date->after(DATE::SUMMER_START) && $date->before(DATE::SUMMER_END)) {
```

should be rewritten to

```
if ($date->isInSummerPeriod()) { …
```

Another comment type you will sometimes encounter is the separator comment, e.g. something like

```
// --------------------------------------------
```

or

```
################################################
```

Those are usually indicative that the code they are used in is doing too much. If you find this in a class, check the responsibility of the class and see if some parts of it are better refactored into a standalone class.

As for API docs, the common notation is [PHPDoc](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/), e.g.

```
/**
 * Short Desc
 *
 * Long Desc
 * 
 * @param  type $name description
 * @return type       description
 */
 public function methodName($name) { …
```

I would argue that you can omit Short and Long Desc if the remaining method signature clearly communicates what it does. However, that requires a certain discipline and knowledge in how to actually write [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882). For instance, the following is totally superfluous:

```
/**
 * Get the timestamp property
 *
 * The method returns the {@link $timestamp} property as an integer.
 * 
 * @return integer the timestamp
 */
 public function getTimestamp() { …
```

and should be shortened to

```
/**
 * @return integer
 */
 public function getTimestamp() { …
```

Needless to say, whether you go for full API docs or not also depends on the project. I'd expect any framework I can download and use to have full API docs. The important thing is just that whatever you decide to do, do it consistently.

Comment: `if (FALSE === $date->isInSummerPeriod())` yoda style ftl. Besides that, when a function is expected to return a true it's perfectly fine to use `if(!func())`...

Comment: `(FALSE === something)` being unreadable itself. I believe good Martin would wrote it as just `if ($date->isInSummerPeriod())` with this function returns boolean already, making strict comparison unnecessary.

Comment: a doublet, lol :) Excellent point on avoiding comments though, a gem in this wholly remarkable answer.

Comment: @Thief @Col the Refactoring book actually suggests to use the negated form `isNotInSummerPeriod` which I personally find suboptimal due to negations being somewhat more difficult to grasp. I use Yoda because I often overlook the `!` in `if (!$date->…`. Also, putting the argument to compare to left hand avoids accidental assignment in statements like `if($foo = TRUE)`, though addmittedly, this doesnt apply for the above example, but I've grown accustomed to Yoda by now, so I use is consistently. Feel free to use `!` or `notInSummer` or switch comparison.

Comment: changed the summerPeriod example to avoid further discussion about the above arguments.

Comment: +1 @Gordon for enlightening suggestions! Personally I like the `Short Desc // Long Desc` DUAL approach very flexible. I see that you do not recommend/use the `########`  much, any reasons? Curious!Cheers!

Comment: @Sam no specific reason. It's mainly because they are not used in PHPDoc style API docs and I always used Java style single line comments, e.g. `//` and never bothered to change that.

Comment: @Gordon, must hv been accidental while archiving some of my questions from non-answered to answered. I must have been drunk! cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use the phpdoc standards. Here's a [quick start](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.quickstart.pkg.html) for beginners.

I'm sure you've seen comments like this:

```
/**
 * example of basic @param usage
 * @param bool $baz 
 * @return mixed 
 */
function function1($baz)
{
   if ($baz)
   {
      $a = 5;
   } else
   {
      $a = array(1,4);
   }
   return $a;
}
```

Commenting this way makes it not only easy for most PHP-developers to read, but you can also generate nice documentations.

Comment: ... and many IDEs can parse them too :) That makes code completion a powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

To me every one of them looks equally readable.
I am using both one-liners and multi-line comments as well.

Being highlighted in gray, they are always visible and distinct from other code.
I've seen not a single problem with comments readability before

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common to use phpdoc [guidelines](http://www.phpdoc.de/kongress/doccomments.html) for commenting. This includes annotations for generating a documentation.